# How to pass parameters from one feature to another for form field?

Tags: karate

I have a feature A with:

```
* form field username = 'user@gire.com'
* form field password = 'usergire'
```

And another one with:
`* def token = call read ('A.feature') here` I would like to send `username` and `password`.
I followed examples in **Calling other *.feature files** but it doesn't work? Is it possible to do this in Karate? Because I need to call A.feature in other features and send 2 paremeters. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the doc carefully: [Calling other Feature files](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files). In feature A:

```
* form field username = email
* form field password = password
```

And call this:

```
* call read('A.feature') { email: 'user@gire.com', password: 'usergire' }
```

Comment: you must be missing something. if you still have problems, create a working example and submit an issue on GitHub.